# Create point with Geojson and coordinate table

Tags: javascript, function, leaflet, mapbox, geojson

I am currently working on a blog using the template "Fly to a location based on scroll position". However, i have a huge amount of points to display due to the use I'm making of it. Therefore, I intend to create a table that would contain the coordinates of the marker to display on the map. However, I don't manage to get a fully functional table. I can see in my code that the for loop is being ran, but the markers don't display. 
I know i have to use function to put parameter but i don't know how whith Geojson. 
Could you help me with this issue?

Ruman

code

```
var tab_coordo = [-5.949547290802002,54.6500264517435,-9.42651,52.97188,-9.465258121490479,51.94015569078675,12.352237701416016, 45.4577225021236];

for (tab_coordo = 0; tab_coordo < tab_coordo.length; tab_coordo++) {
    var geojson ={  
        "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point", "coordinates": [tab_coordo, tab_coordo++]//ireland cavehills 
        },
            "properties": {
                "title" : "jaimiejourneys",
                "video": ("<iframe src='https://www.instagram.com/p/BWbCDZKA-Nu/embed' width='200' height='200' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>")
            }
        },
        ]
    }                   

// add markers to map
geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {

// create a HTML element for each feature
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';

    // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el, { offset: [-50 / 2, -50 / 2] })
    .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
    .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // add popups
    .setHTML('<p>' + marker.properties.video + '</p>'))
    .addTo(map);
});
```

}

Comment: `tab_coordo < tab_coordo.length` expects number on the left side and an array on the right side. You need two different variables with two different names

Comment: hi thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes I agree on this part. I will change it. My main issue is how to use a function that includes the Geojson variable that takes the coordinates of the table as parameters? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It resolved thanks for helping :)

```
var tab_coordo = [
-5.949547290802002, 54.6500264517435,
-9.42651,52.97188,
-9.465258121490479,51.94015569078675,
12.352237701416016, 45.4577225021236
12.411632537841797, 45.488298185683945
];
var coordo= tab_coordo.length;
for (var inc = 0; inc < coordo; inc=inc+2) {    
//var inc_coordo = inc;
var geojson ={  
        "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point", "coordinates": [tab_coordo[inc], tab_coordo[inc+1]]
            },
            "properties": {
                "title" : "jaimiejourneys",
                "video": ("<iframe src='https://www.instagram.com/p/BWbCDZKA-Nu/embed' width='200' height='200' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>")
            }
        },
        ]
}
```